# Bounding the norm of algebraic number of given degree and height

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $\alpha \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ of degree $\leq d$ and such that $h(\alpha)\leq h$. Denote $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

(Here I use the definition $h(\alpha)=\frac{1}{d}\sum_{p\in spec(\mathbb{Z})}{\sum_{\sigma:K\to \mathbb{C}_{p}}}log^{+}|\sigma(\alpha)|_{p}$, where p-adic norm is taken for non-zero p and regular norm for $p=(0)$, $log^{+}x=max\{0,logx\}$, and $\mathbb{C}_{p}$ is the completion of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$).

I wish to find a bound from above for $|\alpha|$ in terms of $d$ and $h$. To this end, I am trying to bound the coefficients of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, say, $f_{\alpha}\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a minimal primitive polynomial for $\alpha$. The problem is that I don't know how to bound the coefficients of this $f_{\alpha}$, because I don't know how to relate the norm of $\alpha$ to the norm of its Galois conjugates.

More specifically, if $a$ is the leading coefficient of $f_{\alpha}$, then we have a formula:

$|a|\prod_{|\alpha_{i}|\geq1}|\alpha_{i}|=e^{dh}$

Where $\alpha_{i}$ are the galois conjugates of $\alpha$, which follows from the more general Jensen's formula for mahler measure.

My question: Can this formula be used to bound $|\alpha|$? If not, how would find a bound? Surely there is a reference for this question?

Thank you very much!

Comment: So you know that $\prod_p |n|_p = |n|_\infty^{-1}$ ie. $h(\alpha) = -\frac1d \log |N_{K/Q}(\alpha)|_\infty=-\frac1d \log |f(0)/a|_\infty$ which doesn't imply a bound for $|\alpha|_\infty$

Comment: But nothercott's theorem implies there are finitely many algebraic numbers of this form, so of course there should be an upper bound for $|\alpha|$

Comment: The height is the sum over all places not only the finite ones, and for $\Bbb{A}^1\subset\Bbb{P}^1$ it involves a $\max(|\alpha|_v,|1|_v)$

Comment: I edited accordingly, it was a typo. Still, doesn't nothercott's result implies there is an upper bound for such numbers?

Comment: OVER ALL PLACES thus if $|\alpha|_\infty$ is large then so is $\max(\log |\alpha|_\infty,0)$ and $\sum_v \max(\log |\alpha|_v,0)$

Comment: For $a/b\in \Bbb{Q}$ then $h(a/b) =\max(\log|a/b|_\infty,0)+ \sum_p \max(\log|a/b|_p,0)$ where $|a/b|_p = p^{-k}$ if $a/b=p^k c/d, p\nmid cd$.

Comment: exactly... 
First of all, $p=0$ corresponds to the infinite case. Secondly, I am saying that if the height (and degree) is bounded then the norm is bounded, not the other way around...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\beta\in \overline{\Bbb{Q}}$ let $V(\beta)$ be the set of isomorphism classes of absolute values on $\Bbb{Q}(\beta)$ with the normalization $|p|_v= p^{-1}$ if $|.|_v$ is above $\Bbb{Q}_p$

and $$h(\beta) = \frac1d\sum_{v\in V(\beta)} \max(\log|\beta|_v,0), \qquad d=[\Bbb{Q}(\beta):\Bbb{Q}]$$

The monic minimal polynomial of $\beta$ is $$f(X)=\prod_{\sigma\in Hom(\Bbb{Q}(\beta),\Bbb{C})} (X-\beta)\in \Bbb{Q}[X]$$
Since $|\beta|_{\Bbb{C}}\le e^{d\, h(\beta)}$ its coefficients are bounded by those of $$(X-e^{d\, h(\beta)})^d$$

Thus all we need is an integer $n$ such that $n f(X)\in \Bbb{Z}[X]$. We can take $$n= \prod_p\prod_{v\ |\ p, \ |\beta|_v > 1} |\beta|_v^d\le e^{d^2\ h(\beta)}$$
With this $n$ then $|n\beta|_v\le 1$ for all finite place thus $n\beta\in \overline{\Bbb{Z}}$ and $\prod_{\sigma\in Hom(\Bbb{Q}(\beta),\Bbb{C})} (X-n\beta)\in \Bbb{Z}[X]$

And hence the coefficients of the $\Bbb{Z}[X]$ minimal polynomial of $\beta$ are bounded by those of $$e^{d^2\ h(\beta)}(X-e^{d\, h(\beta)})^d$$